# Multi domains blazor web application

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a single blazor server project. But I will have multiple domains.

What i want to do is to dedicate folders for each domain.

But some razor pages will be the same for all domains.

Example:

```
www.mydomain1.com/Page1 -> Pages/mydomain1.com/Page1.razor
www.mydomain1.com/Page2 -> Pages/mydomain1.com/Page2.razor

www.mydomain2.com/Page1 -> Pages/mydomain2.com/Page1.razor
www.mydomain2.com/Page2 -> Pages/mydomain2.com/Page2.razor

www.mydomain1.com/CommonPage -> Pages/CommonPage.razor
www.mydomain2.com/CommonPage -> Pages/CommonPage.razor
```

How can i do that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you need to look at the actual output of a published Blazor project.  Other than wwwroot and some culture things, there ARE no folders.  Can you please explain your purpose more?  It may be that you just need a separate folder for reusable components.  Or it may be that you need to set up some kind of routing in IIS.

Comment: Yes i know folders in Pages won't be mapped to http website. I do not want final users to see this folders. What i want to do is to allow a developper to easily create new domains: He will just have to create a new folder dedicated to the new domain. If it does not do that, system should take a default folder. Please not i am not working with IIS, but Azure App Service

Comment: A new folder, which holds what, exactly?  How do you want to deploy a newly-created domain?  Will your dev be compiling it and publishing it?

Comment: folder1 for www.domain1.com ; folder2 for www.domain2.com ; My dev will be compiled and published of course

Answer (score 0):

*This is not supposed to be the answer yet. It's a way to get there. Based on your comments, I'll refine this post and adding examples s, etc. I want to make sure first that I'm going in the right direction.*

I see multiple ways to achieve what you have in mind, but there are not "built" in Blazor way to do it.

Since you want to display different components within your Blazor application, it has to be handled by Blazor and not the "outer layer" of ASP. Core. So, classical redirects won't work here.

The only way you have in Blazor is the `NavigationManager`. Let's start with the component  `Page1.razor`. I'd recommend putting this component inside a wrapper container. This container chooses, based on the URL, which component should be loaded. I call this component `Page1Wrapper.razor`.

**Page1Wrapper.razor**

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@page "/Page1"

@switch (_host)
{
    case "www.mydomain1.com":
    default:
        <Page1ComponentForMyDomain1></Page1ComponentForMyDomain1>
        break;
    case "www.mydomain2.com":
        <Page1ComponentForMyDomain1></Page1ComponentForMyDomain1>
        break;
}


@code {
    private string _host;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _host = new Uri(NavManager.BaseUri).Host;

        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

There would be a lot of redundancy for each wrapper component. However, there are ways to generalize it, like create an own attribute for the components that should differ based on the URL and adding logic to create the wrapper components on the fly.

**Page1ComponentForMyDomain1**

```
@attribute [DomainSpecificRoute("/Page1","www.mydomain1.com")]
.. existing content goes here

@code {
existing code goes here
}
```

Please, let me know what you are thinking and what option you would like to explore in more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but i would like no additionnal attributes or switch in razor pages. What i am looking for is a common code which checks if mydomain1.com folder exists and automaticly routes to the good folder's razor page. Razor pages should only contains on the top @page "/Page1" Thanks

Comment: This would require implementing your own router, which is a very good exercise in understanding Blazor. I would need some time to prepare an example.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i've tried but it does not work because i cannot have 2 razor pages with @page "/Page1" even if they are in 2 different folders...

Comment: I've done something comparable in the past and it worked. At least I remember so :). I need some time to revisit my notes and put an example together. Hopefully, you can read something here tomorrow.